# Get and Update google docs version

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I have a google document with several named versions that were added using the UI, I need the ability to

- Get a `link` to a document that will point to a specific version, using API
- Add a new version, using API.

The idea behind that is to use this `link` to connect a document to a specific commit in the git repository

[image]

Can't find any reference in docs, I found some issues in Stack overflow but no one gives a proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer for Question 1:

> Get a link to a document that will point to a specific version, using API

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for retrieving the URL for directly opening Google Document for each revision. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions) As a workaround, when the Google Document is opened for each revision as the export, this can be used.
In this case, you can use the following sample request.

```
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{documentId}/revisions?fields=*'
```

When this request is run, the following result is obtained.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revisionList",
  "revisions": [
    {
      "kind": "drive#revision",
      "id": "1",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
      "modifiedTime": "###",
      "published": false,
      "lastModifyingUser": {
        "kind": "drive#user",
        "displayName": "###",
        "photoLink": "###",
        "me": true,
        "permissionId": "###",
        "emailAddress": "###"
      },
      "exportLinks": {
        "application/rtf": "###",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "###",
        "text/html": "###",
        "application/pdf": "###",
        "application/epub+zip": "###",
        "application/zip": "###",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": "###",
        "text/plain": "###"
      }
    },
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ]
}
```

- For above returned value, for example, when `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` of `exportLinks` at the 1st index is retrieved, that is the URL of DOCX data for the revision number `1`.
- In this case, the URL is not publicly shared. So please be careful this. When you want to access to it, it is required to login. And when you want to make users access to it, please share it with the users.

#### Answer for Question 2:

> Add a new version, using API.

In this case, unfortunately, there is not method for creating the revision in "Revisions" of Drive API. But, when the Document is updated using Google Docs API and Google Apps Script, new revision number is added. I thought that this might be used for your situation.

### References:

- [Download and publish file revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions)
- [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions)